# UISearchBar hides out in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've been stuck on this issue for some days and couldn't figure out a solution.

Background:

I were rebuilding a code which built on XCode 4 to XCode 6  for making it compatible for iOS 7 and 8. On doing so, I found a weird problem as described in title, the `UISearchbar` gots invisible when tapping searchbar.
Since the codebase I'm working on is very large, I decided to reproduce this in a sample application and posting the details of sample app here.

[image: UISearchBar placed in StoryBoard]
As like in this image attached, `UISearchBar` is inside a `UIView` contained in a `UITableView`.

On tapping searchbar, it gets transitioned to some other location on left as like this.
[image: Searchbar moves on to left]

PS: I couldn't take searchbar out of view and place it in tableview as it is creating some other issues in navigation. So please provide a solution which can make the searchbar positioned to its parent view itself.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you placed a UIView and search bar inside a tableview?

Comment: yea, searchbar inside view and view inside tableview.

Comment: That's not the correct approach. You should not place anything over a table view. If you want to show anything in the tableview, then use the table view cells. For your requirement, you can have the search bar just over the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly setting frame for UISearchBar on iOS8 solved the issue for me.

```
CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenSize.width, 44);
```